# Child processes will not exit

Tags: fork, parent-child, exit, child-process

I have the most puzzling behavior with child processes not exiting. I don't even now if they are executing at all. My code spawns two child processes at these line points:

```
Poco::ProcessHandle ph = Poco::Process::launch(cmd, args, 0, &outPipe, &errorPipe);
ph.wait();
```

and

```
PyRun_SimpleString(data.data() )
```

The debugger will just say a child process was spawned and then hang, waiting for the child process to exit

```
Detaching after fork from child process 38482
```

These two processes are very different, suggesting that the problem is more general than the particular instructions to be executed by the child process.

If anyone has encountered a similar situation of stubborn children, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar problem with Async channels in Poco.
Probably this link helps you.

[Poco AsyncChannel does not exit on forked process exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998019/poco-asyncchannel-does-not-exit-on-forked-process-exit)

Summary: create threads after fork and not before